# How can read from a file in c++?

Tags: c++, ifstream

Please tell me if I did something wrong and how can I fix it. The .txt file is in the same directory with c++ file.

```cpp
string line;
ifstream printCandidates ("printCandidates.txt");
if(printCandidates.is_open())
{
    while(getline(printCandidates, line))
    {
        cout << line << "\n";
    }
} else
{
    cout << "Error!\n";
}
printCandidates.close();
```

Comment: You forgot to tell us what the problem is.

Comment: The shown code is not complete. As it is it will not work. Making it complete it might work. Didn't you test it yourself. If you have no IDE at hand, just use an online compiler.

Comment: It doesn't matter where the c++ file is. The text file needs to be in the same directory where you are running the program. You can use absolute path to avoid such errors.

Comment: [**MCVE on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9ee01a8d52fbc3af) To follow up what @RSahu mentioned: coliru compiles the binary code into the same directory like the sources. This might be done different if you use build-scripts (with e.g. `make`) or an IDE (e.g. VisualStudio).

Comment: Looks fine to me !

Answer (score 1):

Since you used a file name without absolute path, the file will be created in whatever was the current directory when you executed that program. That directory is determined by the calling process. This is completely unrelated to where your C++ files are (indeed, if you are shipping compiled code, the C++ files are at a completely different computer that is possibly not even accessible from the computer the program runs on). Indeed, it is even not necessarily where your program is.

The way to avoid this is to use an absolute path to the file. The simplest way to do this is to store the file at a fixed absolute path, and pass that absolute path to your ifstream constructor. You probably don't want to use your source directory for that, but instruct the build system to copy that file to a fixed location and use that location in your code. How to do that depends on your build system.

You may also consider having the path configurable in your build system, and passing it to your C++ code by macro on the compiler invocation. Most compilers allow this with a command line option like

```
c++ -DCANDIDATE_PATHNAME=\"/path/to/printCandidates.txt\" yourcode.cpp
```

and then in your code you'd write

```
ifstream printCandidates(CANDIDATE_PATHNAME);
```

but the details depend on your compiler and build system.